# Error 451 for AutoCAD VBA

Tags: vba, autocad

The following code is supposed to loop through each line in the drawing and get the startpoint x, y and z values but instead I get

> error 451

I copied this code from something else that works so I am at a loss here.

```
Sub Get_Points()

     Dim ent As AcadEntity
     Dim name As String
     Dim x As Double
     Dim y As Double
     Dim z As Double

     For Each ent In ThisDrawing.ModelSpace

         If TypeOf ent Is AcadLine Then

             name = ent.Handle
             x = ent.StartPoint(0)
             y = ent.StartPoint(1)
             z = ent.StartPoint(1)
         End If

     Next

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to cast the generic entity type into the specific entity type first like this:

```
Sub Get_Points()
     Dim ent As AcadEntity
     Dim acLine As AcadLine
     Dim name As String
     Dim x As Double
     Dim y As Double
     Dim z As Double

     For Each ent In ThisDrawing.ModelSpace
         If TypeOf ent Is AcadLine Then
             Set acLine = ent
             name = acLine.Handle
             x = acLine.StartPoint(0)
             y = acLine.StartPoint(1)
             z = acLine.StartPoint(2)
         End If
         MsgBox name & vbCr & x & vbCr & y & vbCr & z
     Next

 End Sub
```

(also, your `z` was using index 1 just like `y`, so I fixed that as well)

Comment: I tried your code and got the 451 error too, but the code I posted worked perfectly for me, so you may want to double check. I am using AutoCAD 2015.